# Why IntelliJ debugger skips breakpoints on some if statements?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I can't understand why the IntelliJ debugger skips breakpoints on some `if` statements as shown below for those without a check mark.

I thought it might be because the compiler optimizes the code and removes the `if` statements when they are useless –highlighted with yellow color. But in the second case in the shown snippet, although it's very intuitive to be useless and already highlighted, the breakpoint is active

I've tried:

- Clean & Rebuild
- Invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ
- Restart debugger

[image: code snippet example]

Comment: Which JDK are you running on and which are you executing on? Specific version needed. Also, which version of IDEA are you using? Those are essential information missing

Comment: Android Studio 3.3 - 
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018 - 
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64 - 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o - 
macOS 10.14.3 -

Comment: Check the IDE exceptions inside the log file.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project? Please try to run "File | Invalidate Caches"

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, I tried Invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ. Were you able to reproduce the same scenario?

Comment: Do you face the issue with new project? It seems to work fine on my machine.